# How substitute variable in PowerShell SQL query

Tags: sql, function, powershell, parameter-passing, substitution

I need to use a variable in my SQL query. This is my script:

```
function SQLQueryWriteToFile([string]$SQLquery, [string]$extractFile, [string]$facility)
{
   #create sql connection to connect to the sql DB
   $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

   $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=blah;Database=blah_Test;User ID=blah;Password=blah" 
   $sqlConnection.Open()

   #Create a SqlCommand object to define the query
   $sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
   $sqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLquery
   $sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection

   #create a SqlAdapter that actually does the work and manages everything
   $sqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
   $sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $sqlCmd
   $sqlAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=300  #set timeout for query execution to 5 minutes (60x5=300)

   #create an empty dataSet for the query to fill with its results
   $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

   #execute the query and fill the dataSet (then disconnect)
   $sqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
   $sqlConnection.Close()

   #dump the data to csv
   $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile #this may not be comma delimited...need to check

} 

#start here

$SQLquery_Privilege = @"
SELECT *

 FROM "blah_Test".dbo.usr_Person_by_Privileges

WHERE 
       Status in ('Active')  
       and Facility = '$[facility]'
       and Last not like ('%test%')
       and Last not like ('%Test%')

--ORDER BY Last
"@


$extractFiles = @("C:\temp\Privileges_H_Bak.csv","C:\temp\Privileges_E_Bak.csv","C:\temp\Privileges_S_Bak.csv")
$facCode = @("H","E","S")

#Loop through list of files and queries for ProfileLong
for($i=0; $i -lt ($facCode.Length); $i++) {
   SQLQueryWriteToFile $SQLquery_Privilege $extractFiles[$i] $facCode[$i]
}
```

I used the debugger and the query passed into the function does have the $facility variable show in it without substitution.  How do I get it to do the variable substitution?  Also, $facility passed into the function has a value.

There are 0 results showing in each extract files.  When I just had each H,E,S individually in the query, and ran the script, it returns a good amount of rows.

I tried looking at [substitute variable powershell sql](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/using-variables.html) but I can tell my query is still returning 0 rows even though I think I'm doing what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of string substitution (this also protects against SQL injection vectors):

```
$SQLquery_Privilege = @"
SELECT *

FROM "blah_Test".dbo.usr_Person_by_Privileges

WHERE 
       Status in ('Active')  
       and Facility = @facility
       and Last not like ('%test%')
       and Last not like ('%Test%')

--ORDER BY Last
"@

# inside SQLQueryWriteToFile
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLquery_Privilege
$sqlCmd.Parameters.Add('@facility',$facility)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly.  And thanks for pointing out that it protects from SQL injection!